# Error occurring when jbpm timer task invokes

Tags: jbpm

I have a user timer task in my jBPM 6.3 workflow. When a timer task occurs, I get the following error:

> ERROR 2016-06-01 17:35:53
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:146 -
>   error enlisting a JdbcConnectionHandle
>   of a JdbcPooledConnection
>   from datasource jdbc/PostgresDS
>   in state ACCESSIBLE
>   with usage count 1 wrapping a JDBC LrcXAConnection
>   on org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@4baf9c1
>   on a JDBC LrcConnectionHandle
>   on a JDBC LrcXAResource in state NO_TX

My workflow looks like

[image]

And my persistence.xml is:

```
    <persistence-unit name="dms-jbpm" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/TaskAuditorm.xml</mapping-file>

    <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.NodeInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationKeyInfo</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationPropertyInfo</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa.ContextMappingInfo</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.AttachmentImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ContentImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.BooleanExpressionImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.CommentImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DeadlineImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DelegationImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EscalationImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.GroupImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.I18NTextImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.NotificationImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationHeaderImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.PeopleAssignmentsImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ReassignmentImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskDataImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.UserImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model.BAMTaskSummaryImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model.TaskEventImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model.AuditTaskImpl</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I can see, is that jBPM core engine uses JTA for persistence, you should use that (instead of resource_local) in your persistence.xml.  Not sure if that's the only issue though ...